# How to add custom view at particular point in relative layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]Hi am developing android application with graph view. i got an open source graph application to show my values with graph lines. Here i am face problem while adding view. i am not able to add my custom view properly with relative layout. 
Here i attached my custom view alignment .

In that image point 1. is my result while trying to add mt custom view.
But i need to add that as shown in 2. part. 
my custom view is like shown in 3 .part 
I am getting that line starting x,y and ending x,y values. I tried with that values but i got result as 2 part. Please provide me any suggestion 
Or let me know is there any alignments required.

My code is like

```
View View v1=infalter.inflate(R.layout.bullet, null);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rl.setMargins(myX,myY, 0, 0);
mRelative.addView(v1,rl);
```

Comment: Post a screenshot with your actual result, as I don't get it from the image drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the margins for the x, y  point that you got, so the view will start at x, y at the top left, which is what you got. You want to align the bottom center of the view, so you need to calculate this.

So:

top= y - viewHeight

left= x - viewWidht/2

Comment: Your assumption is correct but i am not able to get viewHeight,viewWeight before adding to my layout. It is returning 0 values. Any idea

Comment: Maybe using hardcoded values if your custom view is static or call measure on the custom view for the size to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your values of myX and myY are, but it looks like you're trying to align the top right with your x and y margins applied to the right and top respectively.  If this is indeed the case, you're probably better off with something like this:

```
        rl.setMargins(0, 0, myX, myY);
        rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

The arguments to setMargins go in order as follows: left, top, right, bottom.  If your myX value is the right margin and you want the object right aligned, the code above will specify these two preferences.

Comment: this is adding the view at left corner

Comment: Starting point of added view at my x,y point and it is adding view same as 1st case

Answer (score 0):

While playing with a relative layout to provide a help screen overlay I ran into weird things and had to set margins relative to the bottom right and not upper left. So I had a rule to align the view at the bottom and the right + the margins.

Maybe that will help.